# Make use of a value from a servlet to use it in a normal class

Tags: java, servlets, get, set

My Scenario : 
   I have a servlet and two normal classes. X servlet y Class Z Class.

```
X Servlet code :

    Y y=new Y();
    y.setMap(Map);//Value exists for Map[Found out by sysout]

 Y Class : 
    public void setMap(HashMap<String,String> hash){
    this.hash=hash;
    System.out.println("Set:::"+this.hash.toString());
}

     public HashMap<String, Boolean> getMap(){
          System.out.println("Bean Class:::"+hash.toString());
          return hash;
    }

Z Class: 

Y bean=new Y();
HashMap result=bean.getMap();
System.out.println(result);
```

It results to null. 
Can any one explain why it results in null.

Comment: Where does servlet class came in between ?

Comment: The Map value is obtained in the servlet only. I need to use that value in Z class so i am used the getter setter option. Is anything wrong in my approach?? If not pls let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `Y.setMap` static like so.

```
class Y {
    private static HashMap<String, Object> map;

    public static void setMap(HashMap<String, Object> hash) {
        map = hash;
    }

    public static HashMap<String, Object> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

Your servlet can set the map e.g.

```
 Y.setMap(map);
```

Other classes can reach it using

```
HashMap<String, Object> result = Y.getMap();
```

Comment: you can't use `this` within a static method.

Comment: I don't think this can be used in a static context.